# Filtering Flatlist by User Search - CoinInfo.includes comes back undefined React Native

Tags: react-native, search, filter

I am trying to filter A Flat List by using search.
I am using the Search Component & FlatList from `react-native-elements` and `react-native`.
The code listed below: I am trying to render the whole flatlist or render just the filtered flatlist from the users search text.
The code listed below:

```
this.state = {
      cryptos: [],
      refreshing: true,
      filteredCryptos: [],
      searchText: '',
    };
<SearchBar
          round={true}
          lightTheme={true}
          placeholder="Search ..."
          placeholderTextColor="#000000"
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoCapitalize={false}
          onChangeText={this.search}
          value={this.state.searchText}
        />
        <FlatList
          data={
            this.state.filteredCryptos && this.state.filteredCryptos.length > 0
              ? this.state.filteredCryptos
              : this.state.cryptos
          }
          renderItem={({item}, index) =>
            item !== null ? (
              <CryptoItem
                key={index}
                crypto={item}
                cryptoDisplay={item.DISPLAY.USD}
                onClick={() => this.onClickSubscription()}
              />
            ) : (
              <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
            )
          }
          keyExtractor={item => item.CoinInfo.Id}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
        />
```

Search Function

```
search = searchText => {
    this.setState({searchText: searchText});
    let filteredCryptos = this.state.cryptos.filter(function (item) {
      return item.CoinInfo.includes(searchText);
    });
    this.setState({filteredCryptos: filteredCryptos});
  };
```

Data I am trying to match From the API is `CoinInfo - FullName or Name`.

```
CoinInfo: {Id: '1182', Name: 'BTC', FullName: 'Bitcoin', Internal: 'BTC', ImageUrl: '/media/37746251/btc.png', …}
DISPLAY: {USD: {…}}
RAW: {USD: {…}}
```

Comment: `let filteredCryptos = this.state.cryptos.filter(function (item) {
     let stringValue = JSON.stringify(item.CoinInfo);
      return stringValue.includes(searchText);
    });`

Try this, I hope it will work.

Comment: @Kailash this worked! Also, it is also very literal. For example if i do bitcoin instead of Bitcoin with a capital or BTC vs btc it does not render ... any advice?

Comment: convert both to lower case (stringValue.toLowerCase(), searchText.toLowerCase()). then perform your task. regex can also be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to match the text in the `FullName` or `Name` properties in your search function.

```
search = searchText => {
  this.setState({searchText: searchText});
  
  // searchText empty, reset filtered array
  if(!searchText){
    this.setState({filteredCryptos: []});
    return;
  }
  
  let filteredCryptos = this.state.cryptos.filter(function (item) {
    
    // Defaults to empty string
    let name = item.CoinInfo ? (item.CoinInfo.FullName || item.CoinInfo.Name || "") : "";
    
    // If no such property, skip
    if(!name) return false
    
    // Change to both to lowercase, as you want to match 'bitcoin' and 'Bitcoin'
    return name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
  });
  this.setState({filteredCryptos: filteredCryptos});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert both your search string and searching Object into lowercase string and perform this operation, it will work.

```
search = searchText => {
    this.setState({searchText: searchText});
    let filteredCryptos = this.state.cryptos.filter(function (item) {
      let dataString = JSON.stringify(item.CoinInfo).toLowerCase();
      let searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
      return dataString.includes(searchText);
    });
    this.setState({filteredCryptos: filteredCryptos});
  };
```